# Function to Move Stop Loss to Break Even not working

Tags: mql5, forex

I have attached the code for a function I am using to move the stop loss to break even. I do not see any issue with the code, but I am obviously missing something because it is not working. It is supposed to iterate through all open positions, and if a position is 5 pips in profit the stop loss is to be moved to breakeven.
Here is the code:

```
bool MoveBE()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < PositionsTotal(); i++)
   {
      ulong ticketNum = PositionGetTicket(i);

      if (PositionSelectByTicket(ticketNum) && breakEven > 0)
      {  
      
         Print("MoveBE() function called");

         
         long openPositionType = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
         double currentStop = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SL);
         double openPrice = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN);
         string symbol = PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL);
         
         //The point value for gold is set to .01 but it should be .1
         //double pointValue = SymbolInfoDouble(symbol, SYMBOL_POINT);
         double pointValue = 0.1 ;
         double currentProfit;

         if (openPositionType == POSITION_TYPE_BUY)
         {
            currentProfit = SymbolInfoDouble(symbol, SYMBOL_BID) - openPrice;
            
            Print("Debug: currentProfit =", currentProfit);
            
            if ((currentStop < openPrice || currentStop == 0) && currentProfit >= breakEven * pointValue)
            {  
               
            
               currentStop = openPrice;
               bool modified = trade.PositionModify(ulong(ticketNum), currentStop, PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP));
               
               if (modified)
               {
                  modificationCount++;
                  Print("Stop moved to BE for ticket ", ticketNum, " Count: ", modificationCount);
                  return true;
               }
               else
               {
                  Print("Failed to move stop to BE for ticket ", ticketNum);
                  return false;
               }
            }
         }
         else if (openPositionType == POSITION_TYPE_SELL)
         {
            currentProfit = openPrice - SymbolInfoDouble(symbol, SYMBOL_ASK);
            
            if ((currentStop > openPrice || currentStop == 0) && currentProfit >= breakEven * pointValue)
            {
               currentStop = openPrice;
               bool modified = trade.PositionModify(ulong(ticketNum), currentStop, PositionGetDouble(POSITION_TP));
              
               if (modified)
               {
                  modificationCount++;
                  Print("Stop moved to BE for ticket ", ticketNum, " Count: ", modificationCount);
                  return true;
               }
               else
               {
                  Print("Failed to move stop to BE for ticket ", ticketNum);
                  return false;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return false;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can provide the rest of the code as well.

I tried to add debug codes to monitor the current profit for open positions but even that is not working properly.

Comment: I see your first `if` statement and I wonder whether some essentials are worked out:
    'if (PositionSelectByTicket(ticketNum) && breakEven > 0)'

If the `Print` instruction that follows never gets activated, probably the `breakEven` is not defined or modified properly.